# How do you tell users about surveys?

Tags: user-research, surveys

I'm drafting a user research plan for the next year on a higher ed site, and am interested in including a short online survey in addition to a few other, in-person user testing methods. Our site receives a lot of traffic from different groups (prospective students, parents, current students, faculty/staff), but only the last two groups have email to broadcast that this survey exists.

I suppose my question is really simple. Since many of these visitors are anonymous, what would be a good way to communicate to them that we'd love to hear their opinion of the site, without resorting to a pop-up? Just a link marked "survey" and hoping people see it?

Answer (score 1):

> Internal surveys will generally receive a 30-40% response rate or more on average, compared to an average 10-15% response rate for external surveys. [Source](http://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-blog/survey-response-rates/)

So naturally what you are trying to do is to get as close to that as possible or maybe even beat it.

Heres some ways I like to do it.

- **Offer some sort of reward.** In grad school small coffee gift cards went a long way to getting people to volunteer their time.
- Offer a physical prize or an entry into one prize drawing if you can (make sure to email out or post who won so people know you are honest).
- Can you possibly give them some sort of perk or special privilege for your site?
- Maybe you can put them on an exclusive list for them to hear about something before other users
- Are there any perks you might be able to offer them
- If you cant give them anything maybe **appeal to their willingness to help out**
- Ie help foo.edu improve its course catalog with this Brief survey
- **Make it brief** or keep it as painless as possible to encourage them to do it.
- In your case if your trying to target two different groups you could have a drop down with different cuts of the survey and say (we only ask the most targeted questions to keep it as short as possible)
- sticking with the short theme maybe put the average time users spent on it to lower the barrier of entry (and willingness to do it)
- **People are busy offer them a chance to do it later** Want to help out but dont have the time? -- give us your email for us to email it at a later date
- Give them multiple ways to sign up at the later date (text message email twitter etc)
- **Tell them it will be anonymous** thus to eliminate any other barriers
- **Publish the results online**
- Fans of the open source movement or shared data may be willing to help out if the data will be for all to consume
- Show them links to past survey results that are annonimzied so they trust you.

In short **the three most important factors** are gaining their trust, grabbing their interest, and not loosing that interest.